# Vimeo video player - Android

Tags: android, vimeo, vimeo-api, android-video-player, vimeo-player

Does Vimeo have native video player for android. Upon going through the forums, I would only see that Vimeo will open the player in Webview.

Can anyone please clarify Whether Vimeo has native video player for android instead of showing the video in Webview?

I am a Vimeo pro account holder.

Comment: As far as i know vimeo doesn't have native video player but you can play vimeo video in android player. For that you have to buy some premium membership from vimeo then they'll expose an api, from that you can get pure link for videos and use those links to play your video in android player itself

Answer (score 1):

Vimeo don't have any Native android players.

Instead we got the Video url from them and played it in Exoplayer.